# Test class for a JsonParser in Apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, code-coverage

I'm a newbee with Apex and tryingto test one of my Apex class but just got a coverage of 25%.

I don t even think it is really testing my class , because just some variable declaration and some if statement turns on blue after the test. maybe somebody here can give me some directive for this.

So, I have let say a JsonParser class, that take a Http response as parameter and it is suppose to find to particular values in order to construct one object named crane.

So a crane has as fields:

My object here is a crane and has as fields:

```
public class JsonToCranesParser {
    
    public static List<Crane__c> JsonToCranes(HTTPResponse res) {        
        // create Parser
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
    
        // Define lists       
        List<String> Ids = new List<String>();
        List<String> CraneType = new List<String>();
        List<String> CraneCategory = new List<String>();
        List<String> CraneControls = new List<String>();
        List<String> LoadCapacityType_0 = new List<String>();
        List<String> TrackWidthCraneType_0 = new List<String>();
        List<String> EngineControl_0 = new List<String>();
        List<String> SellerCompany = new List<String>();
        List<Double> DemontageNummer = new List<Double>();
        List<Double> UsablePendulumStrutRadius = new List<Double>();
        List<Double> UsableSolidStrutRadius = new List<Double>();
        List<Double> LoadCapacityWeight_0 = new List<Double>();
        List<Double> TrackWidthCrane_0 = new List<Double>();    
        
        List<String> strList = new List<String>{'craneType','craneCategory','craneControls','loadCapacityType_0','trackWidthCraneType_0','engineControl_0','sellerCompany'};
        List<String> DblList = new List<String>{'dismantlingnumber','usablePendulumStrutRadius','usableSolidStrutRadius','loadCapacityWeight_0','trackWidthCrane_0'};
        String tmp;
        String tmp2;
        
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'id')) {
                while (parser.getText() != 'stringValue'){
                    parser.nextToken();
                }

                parser.nextToken();
                Ids.add(parser.getText());
            }

            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (strList.contains(parser.getText()))) {
                tmp = parser.getText();
                while (parser.getText() != 'value'){
                    parser.nextToken();
                } 

                parser.nextToken();
                parser.nextToken();
                parser.nextToken();
                
                switch on tmp {
                    when 'craneType' {
                        CraneType.add(parser.getText());
                    }  
                    when 'craneCategory' {
                        CraneCategory.add(parser.getText());
                    }
                    when 'craneControls' {
                        CraneControls.add(parser.getText());
                    }
                    when 'loadCapacityType_0' {
                        LoadCapacityType_0.add(parser.getText());
                    }
                    when 'trackWidthCraneType_0' {
                        TrackWidthCraneType_0.add(parser.getText());
                    }
                    when 'engineControl_0' {
                        EngineControl_0.add(parser.getText());
                    }
                    when 'sellerCompany' {
                        SellerCompany.add(parser.getText());
                    }    
                }
            }
            
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (dblList.contains(parser.getText()))) {
                tmp2 = parser.getText();
                
                while (parser.getText() != 'value'){
                    parser.nextToken();
                }

                parser.nextToken();
                parser.nextToken();
                parser.nextToken();
   
                switch on tmp2 {
                    when 'dismantlingnumber' {  
                        DemontageNummer.add(parser.getDoubleValue()); 
                    }   
                    when 'usablePendulumStrutRadius' {
                        UsablePendulumStrutRadius.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                    }
                    when 'usableSolidStrutRadius' { 
                        UsableSolidStrutRadius.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                    }
                    when 'loadCapacityWeight_0' {
                        LoadCapacityWeight_0.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                    }
                    when 'trackWidthCrane_0' {
                        TrackWidthCrane_0.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                    }  
                }
            }
        }

        List<Crane__c> myCranes = new List<Crane__c>();

        // we create a crane list with the data we get from the firestore database

        for(Integer i = 0; i < Ids.size(); i++){
            Crane__c myCurrentCrane = new Crane__c();
            myCurrentCrane.firestore_id__c = Ids[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Crane_Category__c = CraneCategory[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Crane_Type__c = CraneType[i];
            myCurrentCrane.CraneControls__c =CraneControls[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Engine_Control__c = EngineControl_0[i];
            myCurrentCrane.LoadCapacityType__c = LoadCapacityType_0[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Track_Width_Crane_Type__c = TrackWidthCraneType_0[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Seller_Company__c = SellerCompany[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Demontage_Number__c = DemontageNummer[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Load_Capacity_Weight__c = LoadCapacityWeight_0[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Track_Width_Crane__c = TrackWidthCrane_0[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Usable_Pendulum_Radius__c = UsablePendulumStrutRadius[i];
            myCurrentCrane.Usable_Solid_Radius__c = UsableSolidStrutRadius[i];
            myCranes.add(myCurrentCrane);
        }

        System.debug('Ids: ' + Ids);
        System.debug('CraneType: ' + CraneType);
        System.debug('CraneCategory: ' + CraneCategory); 
        System.debug('CraneControls: ' + CraneControls); 
        System.debug('LoadCapacityType_0: ' + LoadCapacityType_0);
        System.debug('TrackWidthCraneType_0: ' + TrackWidthCraneType_0); 
        System.debug('EngineControl_0: ' + EngineControl_0); 
        System.debug('SellerCompany: ' + SellerCompany); 
        
        System.debug('DemontageNummer: ' + DemontageNummer); 
        System.debug('UsablePendulumStrutRadius: ' + UsablePendulumStrutRadius); 
        System.debug('UsableSolidStrutRadius: ' + UsableSolidStrutRadius); 
        System.debug('LoadCapacityWeight_0: ' + LoadCapacityWeight_0); 
        System.debug('TrackWidthCrane_0: ' + TrackWidthCrane_0); 

        List<Crane__c> SalesForceCranes = new List<Crane__c>();
         
        SalesForceCranes = [SELECT Id, firestore_id__c FROM Crane__c];

        // As we want to upsert cranes, we have to get their Saleforce Id if they already exist in Salesforce   
        for(Crane__c var1 : myCranes){
             for(Crane__c var2 : SalesForceCranes){
                 
                 if (var1.firestore_id__c == var2.firestore_id__c) {
                     var1.Id = var2.Id;
                 }
             }       
        }
        
        upsert myCranes;   
        return myCranes;
    }   
}
```

and in my test class, I create test data as an Http Response, and the point is that normally after running my class method, I want to compare if the return values are the expected one like this

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
public class JsonToCranesParserTest {
    @isTest static void testJsonToCranes() {
        //Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockJsonBodyGenerator());
        
        //HTTPRequest req =new HTTPRequest();
        //HTTPResponse res= new MockJsonBodyGenerator().respond(req);
       
        HTTPResponse res= new HttpResponse();
        
        res.setBody('"id": {'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"stringValue": "IdValue1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"craneType": {'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "craneTypeValue1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"craneCategory":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "craneCategoryValue1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"craneControls":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "craneControlsValue1"'+
                    '"loadCapacityType_0":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "loadCapacityType_0Value1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"trackWidthCraneType_0":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "trackWidthCraneType_0Value1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"engineControl_0": {'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "engineControl_0Value1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"sellerCompany": {'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "sellerCompanyValue1"'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"dismantlingnumber": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 10'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"usablePendulumStrutRadius": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 11'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"usableSolidStrutRadius": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 12'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"loadCapacityWeight_0": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 13'+
                    '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                    '"trackWidthCrane_0": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 14');
            
           
        // Call method to test.
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
        // 
        List<Crane__c> cranes = JsonToCranesParser.JsonToCranes(res);
        
        // Verify response received contains fake values
        for(Crane__c var1 : cranes){
          
            System.assertEquals(var1.firestore_id__c, 'IdValue1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.Crane_Category__c, 'craneCategoryValue1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.Crane_Type__c, 'craneTypeValue1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.CraneControls__c, 'craneControlsValue1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.Engine_Control__c, 'engineControl_0Value1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.LoadCapacityType__c, 'loadCapacityType_0Value1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.Track_Width_Crane_Type__c, 'trackWidthCraneType_0Value1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.Seller_Company__c, 'sellerCompanyValue1');
            System.assertEquals(var1.Demontage_Number__c, 10);
            System.assertEquals(var1.Load_Capacity_Weight__c, 13);
            System.assertEquals(var1.Track_Width_Crane__c, 14);
            System.assertEquals(var1.Usable_Pendulum_Radius__c, 11);
            System.assertEquals(var1.Usable_Solid_Radius__c , 12);
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice please?

Comment: Is this new code that you created?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes i created my class and the test class myself